# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).imageMapResize is not a function(…)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, imagemap

The code I found at https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-map-resizer  produces the error:

```
imageMapResize is not a function.
```

How can I fix this error?

```html
<div style="width: 100%; max-width: 1200px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; background-color:#000000; margin-top:70px;">
  <img src="Images/image.jpg" alt="BUNDLES" width="100%" usemap="#Map2" border="0">
  <map name="Map2">
    <area shape="rect" coords="388,680,1189,1022" href="" id="addToCart1">
    <area shape="rect" coords="396,1040,1187,1362" href="">
    <area shape="rect" coords="397,1387,1185,1700" href="" id="addToCart3">
  </map>
</div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="imageMapResizer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
  $('map').imageMapResize();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Is the js being fetched by the browser?

Comment: @aksappy Yes it is from browser.

Answer (score 0):

just use

`imageMapResizer.js`

to

`imageMapResizer.min.js`

There maybe something wrong with the min.

I tried `imageMapResizer.js` it works well.

Comment: @Tomlsion I tired that one but showing same error in google crome.

Comment: @DeviPrasad By the before way, I found use `.min.js` does well, maybe something wrong with your code in `imageMapResizer.min.js`